# WPF: Is there a way to pass your own parameters to a UserControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

Let's be specific: My app has a `UserControl` which contains a `DataGrid`. The `MainWindow` has a `TabControl` with an instance of the UserControl in each `TabItem`. Here's the code:

```
<TabControlHeight="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="tabControl" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TabStripPlacement="Bottom">
    <TabItem Header="ASCE PR-72" Name="tabItem72">
        <local:UserControl_DataGrid x:Name="widget"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="ASCE 48-05" Name="tabItem48">
        <local:UserControl_DataGrid x:Name="gadget"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

I wonder whether I can pass my own parameter such as:

```
Personality="A"
```

to one of the TabItems/UserControls, and

```
Personality="B"
```

to the other.

I need some sort of `WhoAmI` discriminator. Lacking the desirable parameter feature, perhaps I could use code such as:

```
if (myName == "widget")
{
    doThat();
}
else if (myName == "gadget")
{
    doTheOther();
}
```

Disclaimer: I am notorious for asking XY Questions!!

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question derive your own class from TabItem, add a dependency property for Personality and use that instead of a regular TabItem.

Code:

```
public enum PersonalityType
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}

public class MyTabItem : TabItem
{
    public PersonalityType Personality
    {
        get { return (PersonalityType)GetValue(PersonalityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PersonalityProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Personality.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PersonalityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Personality", typeof(PersonalityType), typeof(MyTabItem), new PropertyMetadata(PersonalityType.A));
}
```

And then in your XAML do this:

```
<TabControl>
    <local:MyTabItem Personality="A">Foo</local:MyTabItem>
    <local:MyTabItem Personality="B">Bar</local:MyTabItem>
    <local:MyTabItem Personality="C">Baz</local:MyTabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Note that the Personality field will appear in the Visual Studio Properties editor as well.

For your second question use DataTemplating and/or Data Triggers to select the appropriate templates/styles etc based on the property.

UPDATE: It is actually possible to do with without creating a new TabItem class, if this is what you're after then try Googling "attached properties".

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark. The problem that I see is that my `UserControl` is a `DataGrid` and knows all about it, but AFAIK it has no knowledge of being inside a `TabItem`.

Comment: Updated my answer...you might need to use an attached property.

Comment: Mark: Actually, I just came up with a quick solution (BUT yours is very educational, will definitely explore that feature and add it to my coding repertoire). What I am doing is to control the differences from **Outside** as follows: `widget.dataGrid.Columns[8].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;`